# Consulta a Firebase desde aplicación Android descarga muchos datos

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estoy haciendo una consulta a Firebase desde una aplicación de Android. Las consultas son las siguientes.

**Consulta 1**

```
reference.orderByChild("started").equalTo(true).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {...}
```

Esta consulta devuelve 5 resultados, pero el consumo es de 1.5 MB. Es como si devolviera todos los registros. ¿Qué puede estar sucediendo?

He hecho otra prueba, con la siguiente consulta sí que no se produce ese consumo de datos:

**Consulta 2**

```
reference.limitToLast(5).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {...}
```

Me devuelve también 5 registros, pero en este caso me consume sólo *10 KB*.

¿Cómo podría realizar la primera consulta sin que se produjera ese excesivo consumo de datos?

La base de datos consultada tiene unos 1500 registros.

La estructura de la base de datos es esta:

```
Game: 
          -KW_-cgwIPt5E8lzguds:
                               nivel1: array
                               nivel2: array
                               nivel3: array
                               nivel4: array
                               jugador1: String
                               jugador1Pts: int
                               jugador2: String
                               jugador2Pts: int
                               jugador1End: boolean
                               jugador2End: boolean
                               started: boolean
                               completed: boolean
          -KW_-cgwIPt5E8lztyd5:
                               nivel1: array
                               ....
```

Y el código completo es:

```
reference.orderByChild("started").equalTo(true)..addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            gameOnList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot gamesSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Game game = gamesSnapshot.getValue(Game.class);
                    if(game.isStarted()) gameOnList.add(game);
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Cual es la estructura de la BD?

Comment: ¿cómo estás verificando que devuelva 5 registros? Podemos ver el resto del código?

Comment: He editado la pregunta y he puesto la estructura y el resto del código. He comprobado que devuelve 5 registros con el depurador de Android Studio

Comment: Has indexado la tabla?

Comment: Con los índices entiendo que te ha funcionado, cuanto ha reducido el consumo? :)

Comment: Si, indexando el consume se reduce a pocos kb, gracias Merlí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los operadores **startAt(),endAt() y equalTo()** tienen que recorrer toda la array para filtrarla, en tu caso 1500 registros. Estos operadores tienen que ir acompañados de un índice en este nodo, así facilitaras la búsqueda.

```
{
 "rules": {
 "tuNodo": {
  ".indexOn": ".tuValor"
  }
 }
}
```

Con esto se reduciría bastante el consumo de datos y el tiempo de ejecución. Si quieres más información de cómo indexar los datos, mírate esta [página](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data). Sí aún así es elevado, tendríamos que mirar la opción de desnormalizar los datos. Un saludo!